# else statement not working: else appears when not supposed to. (Python)

Tags: python, if-statement

My code is here:

```
import time

idk = input("Hey whats ur name dude  ")

print(idk)
time.sleep(1.2)
print("Hmmmm")
time.sleep(1.4)
print("thats a cool name dude")
time.sleep(2)
print("hey", idk)
time.sleep(1.1)
print("uh")
time.sleep(1.4)
dot = input("you know, the last time I actually coded was like a year ago :/. ya think i can still code? (yes/no/maybe)    ")
if dot == "yes":
  time.sleep(0.7)
  print("thx. ill try my best")
if dot == "no":
  time.sleep(0.7)
  print("ok. i will reteach myself i guess")
if dot == "maybe":
  time.sleep(0.7)
  print("we will see i guess :]")
else:
  print("RESPOND WITH WHAT I TELL U TO RESPOND WITH U IDIOT >:-( ")
```

In the final part, there is an else statement. whenever I run this and I choose the "yes" or "no" option the else statement appears even though it is not supposed to. By the way, this doesn't happen in the "maybe" option. I don't think that this is an indentation error. I looked through it. I am really confused.

Comment: your else is regarding just last `if`. Try use `elif` instead many `ifs`. Try this: https://www.datacamp.com/community/tutorials/elif-statements-python?utm_source=adwords_ppc&utm_campaignid=1455363063&utm_adgroupid=65083631748&utm_device=c&utm_keyword=&utm_matchtype=b&utm_network=g&utm_adpostion=&utm_creative=332602034364&utm_targetid=aud-299261629574:dsa-429603003980&utm_loc_interest_ms=&utm_loc_physical_ms=1001773&gclid=CjwKCAjwzt6LBhBeEiwAbPGOgTplnkHm_Q-8wJAln_DZeGlz_IWcucKh-FQ6qfslcsSqB-JR6GmARxoCgqUQAvD_BwE

Comment: The `else` is **only** connected to `if dot == "maybe":`, the other two `if`s are entirely separate conditions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is happening here is that the else statement is only affecting the if "maybe". What you need to do here is to only write one if statement and then write elif statements for the rest:

```
if dot == "yes":
...
elif dot == "no":
....
elif dot == "maybe":
...
else:
....
```

Otherwise, if you input "yes", the code will check first if there are any "yes" and print the yes response, but, when it gets to the "maybe" it checks that the statement is false an therefore runs what is inside the else statement.

Sorry if this is formatted wrong, I'm writing on a phone.

Comment: That makes sense. I won't make this mistake again

Answer (score 0):

You should use `elif` instead of `if`.

So when you enter **yes** it goes to the next `if` and sees it's not **no** then it goes to the next `if` and it's not **maybe** so it prints the `else` message.

Answer (score 0):

You should use [`elif`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html) in this case, since the `else` only applies to your last check at the moment:

```
if dot == "yes":
  time.sleep(0.7)
  print("thx. ill try my best")
elif dot == "no":
  time.sleep(0.7)
  print("ok. i will reteach myself i guess")
elif dot == "maybe":
  time.sleep(0.7)
  print("we will see i guess :]")
else:
  print("RESPOND WITH WHAT I TELL U TO RESPOND WITH U IDIOT >:-( ")
```

Comment: Oh, I see my mistake now. Thank you so much! I didn't know Elif was a thing. Now it all makes much more sense.

Answer (score 0):

Your `elif` only pairs with your final `if` statement, which is why the final else statement executes when you select the yes or no options. You can use `elif` for the no and maybe options to make all conditionals part of the same control flow.

https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html